Let $f : R \to S$ be an epimorphism of rings with kernel $K$. If $P$ is a prime ideal in $R$ that contains $K$, then $f(P)$ is a prime ideal in $S$.
Let $f : R \to S$ be an epimorphism of rings with kernel $K$.
If $P$ is a prime ideal in $R$ that contains $K$, then $f(P)$ is a prime ideal in $S$.
I am struggling with this exercise from Hungerford's book. My attempt:
Since $P$ is an ideal of $R$ and $f$ is an epimorphism, $f(P)$ is an ideal of S. Let $A$ and $B$ be some ideals of $S$ such that $AB \subseteq f(P)$. Since $A$ and $B$ are ideals of $S$ and $f$ is a ring homomorphism, $f^{-1}(A)$ and $f^{-1}(B)$ are ideals of $R$.
However, at this point I cannot say $f^{-1}(A)$$f^{-1}(B)$ $\subseteq P$ (because I don't know why it should be true), and therefore cannot say $f^{-1}(A)$ $\subseteq P$ or $f^{-1}(B)$ $\subseteq P$ and conclude, $A \subseteq f(P)$ or $B \subseteq f(P)$. I understand that since $K$ $\subseteq P$ and $f$ is a homomorphism, $f^{-1}(f(P)) = P$. However, I don't see why $f^{-1}(AB) = f^{-1}(A) f^{-1}(B)$ should be true.
Thanks in advance!

I would suggest doing it using elements, not ideals. A general element in $S$ has the form $f(x)$. So suppose $f(x)f(y)\in f(P)$, i.e $f(xy)\in f(P)$. Then there exists some $p\in P$ such that $f(xy)=f(p)$. Then $xy-p\in K\subseteq P$, which implies $xy\in P$. As $P$ is prime we get $x\in P$ or $y\in P$, and thus $f(x)\in f(P)$ or $f(y)\in f(P)$.

Thank you @Mark. However, we are not given that the rings $R$ and $S$ are commutative. So, I thought I need to use the "ideal definition" of prime ideals.

@MustafaTurkmen Ok, sorry, I'm not used to using prime ideals in the non commutative case. However, the same idea should work. You basically need to show that $f^{-1}(A)f^{-1}(B)\subseteq P$, and you are pretty much done. It is clearly sufficient to show that if $a\in f^{-1}(A)$ and $b\in f^{-1}(B)$ then $ab\in P$. But that follows by the same argument. We have $f(ab)\in AB\subseteq f(P)$, so take $p\in P$ such that $f(ab)=f(p)$...
